# Continuous cbind-ed daily and weekly data with R?

Tags: r, aggregation, xts, quantmod

I want to bind daily and weekly data continously (without NA) I am using this code for that purpose but I have two problems.

```
library(quantmod)
aapl=getSymbols("AAPL",from="2015-01-01",auto.assign=F)
d_aapl=Cl(aapl)/Op(aapl)
head(d_aapl)
w_aapl=to.weekly(d_aapl)

head(w_aapl)
res=cbind(d_aapl,Cl(w_aapl))
head(res,8)
```

the first problem is with `w_aapl=to.weekly(d_aapl)` logically it should only perform `to.weekly` function only to `d_aapl` variable but its performing it to all the columns except volume and adjusted close. what is happening here?

```
           d_aapl.Open d_aapl.High d_aapl.Low d_aapl.Close
2015-01-02   0.9815064   0.9815064  0.9815064    0.9815064
2015-01-09   0.9811617   1.0243522  0.9811617    0.9941422
2015-01-16   0.9702487   1.0069699  0.9702487    0.9902831
2015-01-23   1.0081603   1.0194087  1.0055072    1.0060552
2015-01-30   0.9943731   1.0221802  0.9708237    0.9895270
2015-02-06   1.0049131   1.0089451  0.9909182    0.9909182
```

The second problem is with the output `res`. After column binding I expected some of the days will be populated with `NA` but instead of `NA` I want to use previous data

```
curren result
           AAPL.Close d_aapl.Close
2015-01-02  0.9815064    0.9815064
2015-01-05  0.9811617           NA
2015-01-06  0.9973719           NA
2015-01-07  1.0051306           NA
2015-01-08  1.0243522           NA
2015-01-09  0.9941422    0.9941422
2015-01-12  0.9702487           NA
2015-01-13  0.9891412           NA

wanted

            AAPL.Close d_aapl.Close
2015-01-02  0.9815064   0.9815064
2015-01-05  0.9811617   0.9815064
2015-01-06  0.9973719   0.9815064
2015-01-07  1.0051306   0.9815064
2015-01-08  1.0243522   0.9815064
2015-01-09  0.9941422   0.9941422
2015-01-12  0.9702487   0.9941422
2015-01-13  0.9891412   0.9941422
```

How to do it?

Comment: Use `zoo::na.locf()` or `tidyr::fill()` for your second problem.

Comment: Set the OHLC argument for your first problem: `to.weekly(d_aapl, OHLC=FALSE)`. See `?to.weekly`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual answer to your first problem, in which you are asking what is happening: `w_aapl=to.weekly(d_aapl)` is simply returning the OHLC of your daily `d_aapl` time series (which is a univariate series) on a weekly scale, although the first few rows (and last few) of the weekly data might not make that so clear. (It has nothing to with adjusted prices or volumes in the context of your question.)

The timestamps in `w_aapl` correspond to the last available day in each weekly aggregation by default (read about `?to.period`'s `indexAt` argument if you wish to change the timestamp to the start of the week, but this is a side point to answering your question), which runs from Monday to Sunday each week (The data for Monday being the first day of the next week).

Since you have no data on the weekends, your timestamp will be the last Friday in each week (but it would be Sunday if Sunday data was included).  Maybe this will help in seeing what is going on:

```
class(coredata(d_aapl)) <- "character"
v <- xts(order.by = index(d_aapl), x = weekdays(index(d_aapl)), dimnames =   list(NULL, "Weekday"))
head(merge(d_aapl, v), 20)

#             AAPL.Close          Weekday    
# 2015-01-02 "0.981506445654964" "Friday"   
# 2015-01-05 "0.981161686386908" "Monday"   
# 2015-01-06 "0.997371888517253" "Tuesday"  
# 2015-01-07 "1.00513062514358"  "Wednesday"
# 2015-01-08 "1.02435224688221"  "Thursday" 
# 2015-01-09 "0.994142220540378" "Friday"   
# 2015-01-12 "0.970248685084346" "Monday"   
# 2015-01-13 "0.989141173831105" "Tuesday"  
# 2015-01-14 "1.00696993757364"  "Wednesday"
# 2015-01-15 "0.971090909090909" "Thursday" 
# 2015-01-16 "0.990283088762806" "Friday"   
# 2015-01-20 "1.00816028405639"  "Tuesday"  
# 2015-01-21 "1.00550716857753"  "Wednesday"
# 2015-01-22 "1.01940867006333"  "Thursday" 
# 2015-01-23 "1.00605520909915"  "Friday"   
# 2015-01-26 "0.994373131604943" "Monday"   
# 2015-01-27 "0.97082370522725"  "Tuesday"  
# 2015-01-28 "0.980277148183554" "Wednesday"
# 2015-01-29 "1.02218020976616"  "Thursday" 
# 2015-01-30 "0.989527044095827" "Friday"
```

Specifically for your data, each row will take the data from Monday to Friday, and assign the Friday timestamp:

- The first weekly data entry `2015-01-02` is a special case which takes the values between `2014-12-29` (A Monday) to `2015-01-04` (A Sunday), which is just one value on Friday at `2015-01-02` (which is why OHLC = C for the first weekly bar).
- The data for `2015-01-09` row will taken from `d_aapl` between `2015-01-05` to `2015-01-11`. You can see the high was clearly from `2015-01-08`, the low on `2015-01-05`, the open was the first value in the range which is `2015-01-05`, the close the value for `2015-01-09`.
- the data for row `2015-01-16` will be taken from `d_aapl` between `2015-01-12` to `2015-01-18`, etc....

Regarding your second question, other answers already provided work well, but you might also consider seeing `?merge.xts` and its `fill` argument, which is more concise in certain situations: `res=merge(d_aapl,Cl(w_aapl), fill = na.locf)`

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following line:

```
res$d_aapl.Close <- na.locf(res$d_aapl.Close)

> res
           AAPL.Close d_aapl.Close
2015-01-02  0.9815064    0.9815064
2015-01-05  0.9811617    0.9815064
2015-01-06  0.9973719    0.9815064
2015-01-07  1.0051306    0.9815064
2015-01-08  1.0243522    0.9815064
2015-01-09  0.9941422    0.9941422
2015-01-12  0.9702487    0.9941422
2015-01-13  0.9891412    0.9891412
```